# In a stream audio with html5<audio>.why can't write currentTime ? Or has other method to change the playback progress?

Tags: http-headers, html5-audio

I looked at the sample Mark , and now also runs very well.
http://streaming203.radionomy.com/Air-Jazz?group=0&countrycode=US

But the audio’s src is a stream audio, how to change the playback progress ?
Code audio.currentTime = XXX can not run. audio.currentTime and audio.duration is well.

The point at which you need to set it in the http service or html5′s audio above? Who has a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should response the following headers when streaming:

- Content-Type   => "audio/mpeg"
- Content-Length => "total_bytes"
- Content-Range  => "bytes 0-xxx/total_bytes"
- **Accept-Ranges  => "bytes"**

especially the last one.